# Existence of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\left\vert\,\log\left(x\right)\,\right\vert}{\sin\left(\sqrt{\,x\,}\,\right)}\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$
\mbox{Find out if the following improper integral exists:}\quad
\int_{0}^{1}{\left\vert\,\log\left(x\right)\,\right\vert\over \sin\left(\sqrt{\,x\,}\,\right)}\,{\rm d}x
$$

We have that ${\left\vert\,\log\left(x\right)\,\right\vert\over \sin\left(\sqrt{\,x\,}\,\right)} \sim_0 \frac{\left\vert\,\log\left(x\right)\,\right\vert}{ \sqrt{x}}$ and
$\left\vert\,\log\left(x\right)\,\right\vert =_0 o(\sqrt{x})$, so if I had to guess I'd say the integral exists.

Is this true? How do I **rigorously** show it?

Comment: Show that, for some $\epsilon$ and any $x<\epsilon$, the expression is less than $x^{-3/4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ the sine function is concave, hence $\sin x\geq\frac{2}{\pi}x$. This gives:
$$0\leq I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log x}{\sin\sqrt{x}}\,dx\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}(-\log t)\,dt$$
by substituting $x=t^2$. Since the logarithm function belongs to $L^1((0,1))$, because:
$$\int_{0}^{1}(-\log t)\,dt=\int_{0}^{+\infty}ue^{-u}\,du=\Gamma(2)=1,$$
(by substituing $t=e^{-u}$) this gives that your integral exists and it is bounded by $2\pi$.

By convexity, it is possible to improve this bound up to:
$$ I\in\left(4,\frac{4}{\sin 1}\right).$$

Comment: That's very clever, thank you!